# Не сохраняется путь в PATH

Tags: macos, path

Я прописываю путь в PATH по типу export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin в одном терминале закрываю его и опять открываю этого пути больше нет. Подскажите почему ?

Comment: допишите PATH в конец файла ~/.bashrc (для bash) или ~/.zshrc (для zsh) в зависимости от оболочки которую вы используете. например: `echo "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin" >> ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таким способом Вы прописываете в переменную окружения на время сеанса работы терминала. Когда терминал выключиться вся информация исчезнет. Что-бы внести в переменную окружения информацию на постоянной основе, необходимо текстовым редактором отредактировать файл `~/.profile`, который находится в домашней директории пользователя. И выполнить команду `source ~/.profile` что-бы изменения вступили в силу. Или перезагрузить OS.